# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/proguard/coroutines.pro'

Tags: android-studio, androidx, kotlin-coroutines, meta-inf

when i migrate andoird project to androidx it gives error More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/proguard/coroutines.pro'.
I searched a lot but no one solution can't work.please provide code if any solution found.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's too late, but you can add an exclusion as part of your **packagingOptions** located in **build.gradle**

```
android {
    // ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/coroutines.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: I use pickFirst instead of exclude, it also works.